# Application freezes after adding audio Player.setSourceUrl(widget.audioURL);

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new, I add AudioPlayer.setSourceUrl(widget.audioURL); in initState to load the duration after my application freezes. Maybe there are other ways to do it. I will be grateful if you help me.

my code:

```
void initState() {
    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
      if (event == PlayerState.playing) {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = true;
        });
      } else if (event == PlayerState.paused || event == PlayerState.stopped) {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = false;
        });
      } else if (event == PlayerState.completed) {
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = false;
          position = const Duration();
        });
      }
    });

    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      setState(() {
        position = newPosition;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
    });
    
    audioPlayer.setSourceUrl(widget.audioURL);


    super.initState();
  }
```